# Conneting PCs on Local IP, but on different subnet through Remmina

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remmina

I access a windows desktop on IP `10.11.12.13` from my Ubuntu desktop on IP `10.11.12.14` through Remmina using `RDP` protocal (changing `Security` to `negotiate`, and keeping everything default in Remmina.), but for the same settings, I am unable to connect another windows PC on ip `10.11.15.16`.

By seeing the IP, could anyone here please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really mean IP 10.11.15.16? (The one you can't connect to).
10.11.15.16 is on a different subnet than the other two.

Comment: Yes, It is 10.11.15.16, then how can I connect 10.11.15.16 (on a different subnet) ?

Comment: Can you change the IP address 10.11.15.16 into one on the same subnet? (10.11.12.x)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Issue is resolved. Actually my host computer was on two different IPs, and I was not defining the route (one IP) to connect the other one having different subnet. Now Resolved by selecting the route IP.